# Inequality with sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(r_n)$ and $(s_n)$ be sequences of positive real numbers. Suppose that, for every $\epsilon>0$ the inequality $$r_{n}^{1+\epsilon}<s_n^{\epsilon}$$
holds for all $n$ sufficiently large.

If, for every $\epsilon>0$,  $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}^{\epsilon}=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_{n}=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

One has, for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
0< r_{n}^{1+\epsilon}<s_n^{\epsilon}
$$then, using $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}^{\epsilon}=0$, by the sandwich theorem, for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}r_{n}^{1+\epsilon}=0
$$ and since $u \mapsto u^{\frac1{1+\epsilon}}$ is continuous over $(0,\infty)$ one gets 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}r_{n}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $\epsilon=1$, it follows that $0 < r_{n}^2<s_n$, for all sufficiently large $n$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=0$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_{n}^2=0$, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_{n}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$0<r_n^{1+\epsilon}<s_n^{\epsilon}$$ so by Sandwich Theorem we can say $$\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n^{1+\epsilon}=0$$But this is true for every $\epsilon>0$. So we can take the limit of the above expression as $\epsilon\to0$ thus obtaining $$\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n^{1+\epsilon}=0$$